# If $\vec r = (x,y,z)$ and $\vec r_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$, describe the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ such that $\left|\vec r-\vec r_1\right| = 1$

Tags: vectors, 3d

> If  $\vec r = (x,y,z)$ and  $\vec r_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$, describe the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ such that $\left|\vec r-\vec r_1\right| = 1$.

Can some one prove the solution for me?

I don't understand why the solution is a a sphere with a radius of one, centered at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Vert r - r_1 \Vert$ = $\Big\Vert [x - x_1; \quad y-y_1; \quad z- z_1] \Big\Vert $ = 1
Using the norm definition, we have, $\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z- z_1)^2} = 1$
or ${(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z- z_1)^2} = 1$, which is the equation of a sphere of centre $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and radius $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Because a sphere is defined exactly as:

> the locus of points that has a constant distance (called the radius) from a fixed point that is called the center

and the norm $||\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_1}||$ is just the distance between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

A sphere is the set of points $S$ that are all at the same distance $R$ called the radius from a given point called the center in three-dimensional space Euicledean space $\Bbb R^3$.

This definition is not related to vectors or vector spaces!

Let $r_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ be the center and $R=1$ be the radius. If $r=(x,y,z)\in S$ then
$$d(r,r_1)=1.\tag1$$
By definition of [Euclidean distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) we have
$$d(r,r_1)=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2}.\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, after squaring both sides which does no harm, $S$ is described by the equation
$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2=1.$$
$S$ is called a unit sphere since its radius is $1$.

Note: If we see $\Bbb R^3$ as a [normed vector space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) with Euicledean norm, then
$d(r,r_1)=\Vert\vec r-\vec r_1\Vert$. Then, OP's equation also describes $S$.